# CDAudioManager (cocos2d, ios) how to mix game music and background music so that they play at the same time

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am using CDAudioManager and Cocos2d for my iOs game. I need the iOs player music and game music to play at the same time along with the sound effects. Neither of the modes suits me, since they either shut off the background music or game music.

Here is what I am looking to get:

1. ipod player music playing, launch game. ipod, game music and effects all play together.
   upon resume all the channels should work as they did prior to resume.
2. ipod player music NOT playing, launch game. game music and effects play. as well as after resume.

   ```
   kAMM_FxOnly,                    //!Other apps will be able to play audio
   ---ipod music plays, game effects play. game music doesn't play.
   kAMM_FxPlusMusic,               //!Only this app will play audio
   ---ipod music doesnt play
   kAMM_FxPlusMusicIfNoOtherAudio
   ---ipod music plays, game music doesnt play.
   ```

In all of the modes I have tries the ipod music doesn't resume after minimizing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99% sure that this is not possible. If the iPod player is playing music, and you play game music it'll stop the iPod player. And vice versa.

I have personally never seen (heard) an app that did this, and the general concern of game developers is more along the lines of not interrupting iPod music if it is playing - meaning how to detect if iPod music is playing in order to prevent the game music from playing and interrupting the iPod music (therefore annoying the user).

Comment: thanks. this the publishers requirement. I don't agree with it eather, but still need to figure out the exact solution. It is possible, I heard it in other games.